# Convergence of Diffusion Process Monte-Carlo

Tags: monte-carlo, convergence, numerical-integration

Let $X_t$ be a $d$-dimensional diffusion process initialized at $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$; given as the strong solution to the SDE
$$
X_t = x + \int_0^t a(t,X_t)dt + \int_0^t b(t,X_t)dW_t;
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are predictable functions and $W_t$ is an adapted Brownian motion.  Suppose further, that $f$ is a bounded continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and fix $T>0$.

I would like to know the convergence rate of the naive Monte-Carlo estimate
$$
\mu^n \triangleq \frac1{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_T(\omega_i)),
$$
to the actual expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[f(X_T)\mid X_0=x\right]$.

Comment: Given that the realisations of $X_T$ are iid, the standard law of large numbers operates here as well. The diffusion determines the marginal distribution of $X_TX$ but has no other impact on the convergence of the average, assuming the expectation exists.

Comment: I figured as much... but I was wondering if here was a better order of convergence that O(M) given the extra structure; where $M$ is the number of Monte-Carlo samples.